# How can I use WinDbg with a .NET memory dump file to see how many pooled connections are in each DbConnectionPool object?

Tags: .net, windbg

I have a memory dump that contains .NET DbConnectionPool objects. Rather than tediously iterating through each and every connection pool object and dumping its _totalObjects field,  I would like a quick way to determine how many pooled connections each connection pool contains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using WinDbg scripting, and the Microsoft [PSSCOR2](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1073) debugging extension, you can:

1. Download the PSSCOR2 debugging extension from Microsoft
2. Open the memory dump in WinDbg
3. Load the psscor2.dll (either x86 or x64 version, depending on the bitness of the dump you're dealing with) in WinDbg
4. Paste the following scriptlet into WinDbg and execute:

```
.foreach (pool {!dumpheap -type System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool -short}) {.printf "Pooled connection count: "; !df -field _totalObjects pool}
```